# Clearing AD User Properties Issue

Tags: active-directory, powershell

```
$info = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | ForEach-Object {$_.PSObject.Properties} | Where-Object {$_.value -like "NULL"}

ForEach ($i in $info){
    Set-ADUser -Identity $i.BaseObject.SamAccountName -Clear $i.Name
}
```

Above is the code I'm using to find all AD user fields with a string value of "NULL". I am attempting to clear these fields.

Below is the exception I am routinely seeing, despite the property name clearly existing (as it's pulled directly from the AD property name value.

What am I missing?

```
Set-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: OfficePhone
At line:2 char:5
+     Set-ADUser -Identity $i.BaseObject.SamAccountName -Clear $i.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (RHanson:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Comment: The name attribute is definitely not going to work. It is system only. The others you may want to add try handling for the case where the attribute is not present or just continue.

Comment: This actually worked as-is. There were some fields like "MobilePhone" that disappeared once "mobile" was removed, not sure what to think about that.

Answer (score 2):

Right out of the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser):

> ##### -OfficePhone
>
> […] To modify an object property, you must use the LDAP display name. […]

and

> ##### -OfficePhone
>
> […] The LDAP display name (ldapDisplayName) of this property is telephoneNumber. […]

And here are the docs for the [Telephone-Number attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-telephonenumber):

> CN: Telephone-Number
> Ldap-Display-Name: telephoneNumber

Unfortunately, `Get-ADUser -Properties *` receives both, `OfficePhone` and `telephoneNumber` and I don't know how you can programmatically distinguish real properties from property-aliases built into the module itself.

As a workaround, you can however pipe it through `Get-ADObject` which does not impose alias properties on you:

```perl
$info = Get-ADUser -Filter * |
            Get-ADObject -Properties * |
            ForEach-Object {$_.PSObject.Properties} |
            Where-Object {$_.value -like "NULL"}

ForEach ($i in $info){
    Set-ADUser -Identity $i.BaseObject.SamAccountName -Clear $i.Name
}
```